# rank of a matrix which is a concatenation of full rank matrices

Tags: matrices

Suppose a $6 \times 4$ matrix satisfies the following
[image]

where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are non-zero. Is it true that any $4 \times 4$ submatrix also has full rank?
I think it is true as I can't find a counterexample. But I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you probably want to specify $\theta_1, \sigma_1, \mu_1 \ne 0$ as well. However, there exist examples where all entries are nonzero. Take $\alpha_3 = \alpha_1 + \alpha_2, \beta_3 = \beta_1 + \beta_2, \sigma_3 = \sigma_2, \gamma_3 = \gamma_2$, so the rank $3$ matrices are

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 & \alpha_2 & \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 \\
\beta_1 & \beta_2 & \beta_1 + \beta_2 \\
\gamma_1 & \gamma_2 & \gamma_3
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
\theta_1 & \theta_2 & \theta_3 \\
\sigma_1 & \sigma_2 & \sigma_2 \\
\mu_1 & \mu_2 & \mu_2
\end{pmatrix}$$

(to guarantee rank $3$, one need only require $\gamma_3 \ne \gamma_1 + \gamma_2$, $\theta_3 \ne \theta_2$, $\alpha_1 \beta_2 - \alpha_2 \beta_1 \ne 0$, and $\sigma_1 \mu_2 - \sigma_2 \mu_1 \ne 0$). Removing the middle two rows from the $6 \times 4$ matrix gives

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 & 0 & \alpha_2 & \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 \\
\beta_1 & 0 & \beta_2 & \beta_1 + \beta_2 \\
0 & \sigma_1 & \sigma_2 & \sigma_2 \\
0 & \mu_1 & \mu_2 & \mu_2
\end{pmatrix}$$

which does not have full rank, as the last column is the sum of the first and third.

Comment: An explicit example:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 9 \\
7 & 8 & 9
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 5 \\
6 & 7 & 7
\end{pmatrix} \implies \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 0 & 5 & 9 \\
0 & 4 & 5 & 5 \\
0 & 6 & 7 & 7
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample. If I restrict $\alpha_3 \neq \alpha_1 + \alpha_2$, then the statement is true?

Comment: @Idonknow: Well, if $\alpha_3 \ne \alpha_1 + \alpha_2$ but $\gamma_3 = \gamma_1 + \gamma_2$, then one could delete the row with $\alpha$ (rather than the row with $\gamma$), and still obtain a $4 \times 4$ submatrix with less than full rank. In any case, this seems to be a rather artificial restriction

Comment: Actually I would like to have the statement correct so that I can proceed with my research. So if I impose the two restriction on $\alpha$ and $\gamma$, then the statement is correct?

Comment: Even if you impose both $\alpha_3 \ne \alpha_1 + \alpha_2$ and $\gamma_3 \ne \gamma_1 + \gamma_2$, the statement is still not correct. One could make different examples where $\alpha_3 = \alpha_1$, $\gamma_3 = \gamma_1$ as well, in which the last column is the sum of the first two

Comment: Well, it seems that the statement can only be true under very strict conditions.

Comment: @Idonknow: Yes, that is indeed the point I am making

Comment: So far, I can only think of $\alpha_i \neq \beta_i \neq \gamma_i$ and $\theta_i \neq \sigma_i \neq \mu_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq 3$ so that the statement is true.

Comment: Those (not) equalities are not enough - both types of examples already given do satisfy them. Perhaps your underlying question is: what are (some) conditions for which every $4 \times 4$ submatrix is nonsingular? This should perhaps be a separate question though, as the question here has been answered